# Image gallery with only one div elemement as row, and displaying the images in new lines

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I am learning the Scss, and I trying to create an Image gallery with SASS.

I am trying to include only one div tag for the whole image gallery as row, I don't want to take a new div for each row.

Does that work, taking only one div as row, and creating rows with styles.

I need suggestions.

```
`<div class="image-gallery-items">
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
              <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>`
```

With this code, it's displaying all the images in one line.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you place a minimum reproducible example? This way the community can check a working code. It is preferred to only place the necessary code, to prevent to much noise. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure. I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with flexbox! Flexbox allows you to wrap elements that exceed the width of the parent container. I have included an example of the wrap in action below.

What I did was add "display: flex;" and "flex-wrap: wrap;" to the parent element (.image-gallery-items). This makes it so the child elements will display in rows and then overflow/wrap to the next row automatically if it exceeds the parent width.

```css
.image-gallery-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 600px;
}

.image-gallery-item img {
  width: 190px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-gallery-items">
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
              <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="image-gallery-item">
            <a href="" class="thumbnail">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589682642146-26ac8262b3c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>`
```

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding (=